# Gulp 4 watcher is running but does not detect changes

Tags: gulp, watch

I'm having the following file structure:

```
/ src
  -- app.less
/ gulp
  -- index.js
-- gulpfile.js
```

This file structure is mounted in a vagrant box in /vagrant which means the path to app.less becomes /vagrant/src/app.less. *Yes, I've checked this.*

*gulpfile.js*

```
require('./gulp');
```

*index.js*

```
var paths = {
    less: '/vagrant/src/app.less'
};

gulp.task('less', function () {
    console.log('less function running');

    return gulp.src(paths.less)
        .pipe(less());
});

gulp.task('watch:styles', function () {
    console.log('watch function running');

    gulp.watch(paths.less, gulp.series('less'));
});

gulp.task('watch', gulp.parallel('watch:styles'));
```

*gulp -v* returns:

```
[10:02:05] CLI version 0.4.0
[10:02:05] Local version 4.0.0-alpha.1
```

*gulp watch* returns:

```
[09:45:20] Using gulpfile /vagrant/gulpfile.js
[09:45:20] Starting 'watch'...
[09:45:20] Starting 'watch:styles'...
watch function running
```

I've been using Gulp 4 for over 2 months without problems with the watcher. Since last week the watcher is not responding to files that are being changed. I've tried several editors, I've tried multiple paths like '/vagrant/**/*.less' and '../src/*.less' and even the absolute path to app.less '/vagrant/src/app.less', none of them worked.

After some research I found several issues on the github repo of Gulp 4 about the watcher. Yet, I can't figure out what the problem is. Maybe I'm overlooking an error in my code or something new in the docs, but I'm trying to solve this since yesterday morning without any luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you're using Vagrant. If you have Gulp running on your Vagrant machine instead of on the host it won't detect any changes to files that you make on the host. This is because the events that notify the OS about filesystem changes don't propagate into the VM.

If this is the case, the solution is to simply run Gulp wherever you actually make changes to the files (i.e. if you make the changes on the VM, run it on the VM, if you make changes on the host, run Gulp on the host).

Also maybe make the path relative, instead of tying your implementation to your Vagrant box. i.e. `less: './src/app.less'`.

Comment: This confirms I was looking in the wrong direction. It's not gulp, but the way of mounting of files in my VM. Running gulp watch outside my VM is working fine. I'm going to investigate this further now I know where I have to look. Thanks!

Comment: Is there any other solution? I ask because I'm using Vagrant specifically because I need to execute the pipeline on Linux (due to native code) and yet my editor is running on OSX.

Comment: Well, you could poll, but it'd be slow. There are probably libraries or at least tutorials on how to do that already out there, but the basic gist would be, give something a path, and a callback to execute, it takes the path, and runs a never-ending loop that checks for changes (somehow), then runs the callback each time a change is detected.